# Unsure how to use where clause with two columns

Tags: sql

I just can’t figure this one out. I've been trying for hours.
I have a table like this…

| ID | sample |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | B |

I'm interested in getting all the samples that match 'A', 'B' and 'C' for a given ID. The ID must contain all 3 sample types. There are a lot more sample types in the table but I'm interested in just A, B and C.

Here's my desired output...

| ID | sample |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | C |

If I use this:

```
WHERE sample in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

I get this result:

| ID | sample |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | B |

Any ideas on how I can get my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One ANSI compliant way would be to aggregate using a *distinct count*

```
select id, sample
from t
where sample in ('A','B','C') 
and id in (
  select id from t 
    where sample in ('A','B','C') 
    group by id 
    having Count(distinct sample)=3
);
```

Comment: This solution was spot on. Works exactly as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE sample in (‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’)
```

Should eliminate any other samples such as 'D'.

You could also try the following:

```
WHERE sample = ('A' OR 'B' OR 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what flavor of SQL is being used, but here's an example to work off of:

Postgre - [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/omqqXoGds73tjY84LhzL5u/0)

```
SELECT id 
FROM t
GROUP BY id
HAVING array_agg(sample) @> array['A', 'B', 'C']::varchar[];
-- HAVING 'A' = ANY (array_agg(sample))
--    AND 'B' = ANY (array_agg(sample))
--    AND 'C' = ANY (array_agg(sample))
```

Presto

```
SELECT id 
FROM t
GROUP BY id
HAVING contains(array_agg(sample), 'A')
   AND contains(array_agg(sample), 'B')
   AND contains(array_agg(sample), 'C')
```

Comment: Works great for getting the IDs that match the sample types. Thank you.

Comment: If you do `SELECT id, array_agg(sample)...` it'll give you each id with its accompanying array of samples.